# $_GET and $_POST cannot work on same PHP file + I cant use values from the same file with values from another file ( Advanced search)

Tags: php, mysql, web, advanced-search

I'm developing a website that has a search engine.

let's say we're in index.html that has the following form for search:

```
<form  method ="post" name="search" action="search.php?go">
<input accesskey="s" type="text" size="20px" name="find" id="fastsearch" alt= "search"     value="search..." /> 

<input type="hidden" name="searching" value="yes" />
<input id="searchicon" type="submit" value="" style="border-style: none; background:     url('searchsmall.png') no-repeat;"/>

</form>
```

Then I have this following search.php that has the results in addition to Advance Search below it.

Here's the results part:

```
    $searching = $_POST['searching'];
$find = $_POST['find'];
if ($searching =="yes") { 
    echo "<h2>Results</h2><p>"; 
        if ($find == "") 
        { 
            echo "<p>You forgot to enter a search term"; 
            exit; 
        } 


    //Connect to mysql server
    $con = mysql_connect($DB_HOST, $DB_USER, $DB_PASSWORD);
    if(!$con) {
    die('Failed to connect to server: ' . mysql_error());
    }

    //Select database
    $db = mysql_select_db($DB_DATABASE);
    if(!$db) {
    die("Unable to select database");
    }



    $find = strtoupper($find); 
    $find = strip_tags($find); 
    $find = trim ($find); 
    $date = $_POST['date'];
    $category = $_POST['category'];
    $data ="SELECT * FROM event WHERE upper(title) LIKE'%".$find."%'OR date     LIKE '%".$date."%' OR upper(category_id) LIKE ".$category." ORDER BY date;" ;

    $result=mysql_query($data );




if($result) {
        while($info = mysql_fetch_array( $result )) 
        { 
        echo "<a href=' ".$info['url']." '> ".$info['title']." </a><br/>";
        echo "<br>"; 

        } 
    }
    else 
    { 
    echo "Sorry, but we can not find an entry to match your query<br><br>"; 
    echo "<b>Searched For:</b> " .$find; 
    } 



}
```

Finally here's the advanced search part:

```
<form method ="post" name="search" action="<?=$PHP_SELF?>" style="margin-top: 20px;">
<div class="blockbody" style="width: 700px;">

<h3 class="blocksubhead">Advanced search </h3>
<div class="section">
<!--<div class="blockrow">
<label for="keyword">Search by title: </label>
<input type="text" name="keyword" name="find" >
</div >-->
<div class="blockrow">
<label for="category"> Category </label>
<select name="category">

<option VALUE="CONFERENCE"> Conference </option>
<option VALUE="WORKSHOP"> Workshop </option>
<option VALUE="ACTIVITY"> Activity </option>
</select>
</div>

<div class="blockrow">
<label for="date">Search by date </label>
<input type="date" name="date">
</div>
</div>
<div class="actionbuttons">

<input type="submit" name="search" value="Search" />
</div>
</div>
</div>
</form>
```

My question is, how can I make the php file gets variables from both itself file and from another file sent with its form. I tried to use post for the one in the index and get for those in the advanced search but It's not true to make both post and get in the same file.
And when I made them all get.. An error occurred saying variables ( find, searching, date, category ) are nod declared? :/

Notice that:
*Find is the search word from index.html
*searching is just a value to check if he used search or not, also in index.html

*date is for input date in the same search.php file, at advanced search
*category is for the select value and it depends on the option. also in search.php

BTW that's my first website I developing sorry if I gave too much information and codes but I don't know where exactly is my problem.

Comment: If it's your first website, don't start with the `mysql_*` functions, instead use PDO: http://php.net/PDO

Comment: I don't know what's PDO but I know what mySQL is :P

Comment: With PDO you access your Mysql database. You should learn about PDO, a tutorial is here: http://wiki.hashphp.org/PDO_Tutorial_for_MySQL_Developers

Comment: Both of your forms use `POST`, this is perfectly acceptable. Use `htmlspecialchars($_SERVER['PHP_SELF'])` not `$PHP_SELF`.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if I understand the question, but isn't `$_REQUEST` what you want?

Answer (score 0):

If you want to get them by GET, you have to get them with `$_GET["paramName"]`:

```
$searching = $_GET['searching'];
$find = $_GET['find'];
$date = $_GET['date'];
$category = $_GET['category'];
```

And the form should send them using `GET`:

```
<form method ="get" name="search" action="<?=$PHP_SELF?>" style="margin-top: 20px;">
```

If you want to use `POST`, then use `POST` method as you have in your code.

Anyway, you can always use both methods if you want. You can pass some variables on the `action` attribute of the form, and then send the form by `POST`.

Comment: You should be using `$_SERVER['PHP_SELF']` instead. The other is deprecated. And no, you can still using `GET` if you add parameters to the end of that string.

Comment: Just read a bit about how to use `GET` and `POST`. We can not explain the whole theory here.

Comment: You don't need PHP_SELF. Just remove the action attribute from the <form> tag.